# Rewrite Claimed Identifier when using OpenIDProviderWebForms

Tags: dotnetopenauth

When using OpenIDProviderWebForms example, the Claimed Identifier returned when logging in is in this format:

***https://id.example.com/user.aspx/userID***

I'd like it to look like:

***https://id.example.com/userID***

Any ideas where to handle this?

Note: this is the value returned by DotNetOpenAuth, I can use URL rewrite in IIS to map ***https://id.example.com/userID*** -> ***https://id.example.com/user.aspx/userID***

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to make sure that your preferred URL for user's OpenIDs fit these requirements:

1. They do *not* redirect to some other URL
2. Their HTTP response includes the HTML and/or XRDS discovery tags necessary to qualify as an OpenID Claimed Identifier.

Next, you must add code to your OpenID Provider Endpoint (aka "OP Endpoint) to be able to translate these user URLs into canonical usernames that match accounts in your database (or vice versa). When an authentication challenge comes in, you must validate that the claimed identifier that is trying to log in actually matches the logged in user.

Then just approve the login. DotNetOpenAuth doesn't care which URL you use as the claimed_id, so long as it satisfies the above requirements.